# What is the difference between np.array and np.stack applied to a list of images

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list containing numpy arrays of identical 2D shape
I wanna pack those images for a ConvNet Classifier and I tried two approaches as shown below :

```
X_train = np.array(lst_imgs).reshape(m, 24, 40, 1)/255
XX_train = np.stack((lst_imgs), -1).reshape(m, 24, 40, 1)/255
```

both tensors yield shape of : `(4828, 24, 40, 1)`

However they don't contain the same elements at each index. Can someone please explain to me what is the difference between `np.array` and `np.stack` for this purpose and which one is the most suitable ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: That kind of reshape messes with the images.  Why are you doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.stack` and `np.array` provide exactly the same array, unless you pass a specific axis to the second one.

Let us look at a smaller example on a tiny list of 2d arrays

```
>>> lst = [i for i in np.arange(8).reshape(2,2,2)]
>>> lst
[array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]]), array([[4, 5],
       [6, 7]])]
```

Ok, it is indeed a list of 2 2D arrays each of shape (2,2)

```
>>> np.array(lst)
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 5],
        [6, 7]]])
>>> np.stack(lst)
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 5],
        [6, 7]]])
```

Ok, we have the same result

```
>>> np.stack(lst, -1)
array([[[0, 4],
        [1, 5]],

       [[2, 6],
        [3, 7]]])
```

But if we stack of the third axis (-1 here means last), we also get a 3D array but with elements in a different order.

Here I cannot know which is the correct order for you use case. I have just explained why you get different results.